# Get browsers to store login details on a three field login

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm working on a project that has a three field login form (account, user, password)

is there any way to tell a browser to remember all three fields when trying to save the password for a user? All the browsers I've tested seem to only save the password and username fields.

Comment: I suggest to use a JavaScript code to place account and user name as concatenated string into username field (for example, `account:user`) before submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the:

- Autocomplete property: http://help.dottoro.com/ljdwgiwh.php
- Or HTML5 localStorage: http://www.thomashardy.me.uk/using-html5-localstorage-on-a-form